# Postgis shapefile loader 2.1 error: dbf file can not be opened

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

The .shp, .dbf and the rest of files are fine, I open them in QGIS, AGOL with no problem. In fact, I've tried 3 different layers, and get always the same error.

Anyone can please help, as I really need to migrate my .shp's to postgis, and have no idea of why it's not able to open .dbf?

Postgres v9.3 x86
Postgis shapefile loader v2.1

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS I've tried changing the default character encoding from the default 'UTF-8' to 'ISO 8859-14' but same error.

Comment: Have you tried the shp2pgsql-gui tool?

Comment: And are you trying to import just a .DBF, or an entire shapefile including .DBF?

Comment: Do you close your layers in QGIS or maybe OpenOffice if you opened the DBF like that?
Sometimes, problems only comes from a lock between programs

Comment: could be permissions issues on your .dbf files

Comment: Without seeing the files themselves, there's no way to debug or replicate this.

Comment: thanks everyone, mapBaker I was trying to import an entire shapefile, with all the needed files. ThomasG77 no lock problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pg.html GDAL OGR2OGR to load shapefile data into postgis

**Ogr2ogr Command to import shape into postgis**

ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=myhost user=username dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" your_shapefile.shp

For details
http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet

Comment: Thanks a lot Farhat, what finally seems to have worked (further checking pending) is importing geodatabase files into postgres using OGR2OGR. Great tools, thanks a lot again!

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 11):

I just faced the same problem. I solved it by changing the location of shapefile. It seemed a problem of too long file name. When I moved the files up in folder tree, it worked perfectly, using the plugin.

Comment: this seems to be the good one, worked fine for me aswell, thanks a lot Sergio!

Comment: Also had this problem with PostGIS 2.4.2 and filename probably too long or with special characters (accented letters).

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same error. In my case the solution is also the path name. The path name must not have any special characters like ä,ö or ü.

Answer (score 1):

In PostGIS 2.4 I ran into this because I tried passed DB credentials following earlier versions -- you must pipe to `psql` instead now, e.g.:

`shp2pgsql shaperoads.shp myschema.roadstable | psql -d roadsdb`

In short, this error often shows up for unrelated problems (any kind of bad input or options).

Answer (score 0):

DBF files can be opened by the dint of foxpro dbf recovery software

More info about this solution on [oemailrecovery.com](http://www.oemailrecovery.com/dbf_recovery.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the folder name had a Latin character like `ã` `ê` `ç`. I just renamed it and worked.